# How can I find exact number of minutes without rounding between two dates in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am new to Sql server, I tried datediff several times but failed. All I need is the exact or precise number of minutes including fraction between two dates. E.g if the gap between two datetime fields is 40 seconds than it gives me 0.67 minutes and not 1 minute. Please help.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just Round to whole minutes?  That should give you what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the difference in seconds and divide by 60.0:

```
select datediff(second, date1, date2) / 60.0 as diff_in_minutes
```

This should be close enough for most work.  If you really want, you could use milliseconds instead of seconds.

Comment: I spent a long time finding this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select datediff(millisecond, date1, date2) / 60000.0 as diff_in_minutes
```

Comment: It is giving the datediff function result in an overflow error

Answer (score 1):

To get MILLISECOND accurate value

```
DECLARE @D1 DATETIME = '2015-04-16 21:38:02.610'
DECLARE @D2 DATETIME = '2015-04-16 21:38:29.023'


SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @D1, @D2)* 1.000 / ((1.66667) * POWER(10,5))


RESULT: 0.158477683044633910732
```

Comment: Got error 
Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.